# How to draw path from source to destination by sending latlong of start, and autocomplete and getting back those latlong in json response

Tags: android

1. I am able to draw polylines from json sourcelatlong,json destinationlatlong but not able to draw route as user moves from one of the polylines route.
2. I am sending start latlong and end latlong to server but when user move will latlong change? or will not change as i already selected start and end from autocomplete

### Below is my code code where i am trying to draw route

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements RoutingListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    protected GoogleMap _map;
    protected LatLng start;
    protected LatLng end;
    // @InjectView(R.id.start)
    AutoCompleteTextView starting;
    // @InjectView(R.id.destination)
    AutoCompleteTextView destination;
    // @InjectView(R.id.send)
    ImageView send;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyActivity";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter mAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private List<Polyline> polylines;
    Communicator communicator;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    View view;
    LatLng sourcelatLng;
    LatLng destinationlatlong;
    String id;
    GPSTracker gpsTracker;


    private static final int[] COLORS = new int[]{R.color.primary_dark, R.color.primary, R.color.primary_light, R.color.accent, R.color.primary_dark_material_light};


    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_JAMAICA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-57.965341647205726, 144.9987719580531),
            new LatLng(72.77492067739843, -9.998857788741589));

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
            communicator = new Communicator();
            gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
        }
        //  ButterKnife.inject(getActivity());
        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);l

        starting = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        send = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
        destination = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.destination);

        polylines = new ArrayList<>();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        }
        _map = mapFragment.getMap();

        mAdapter = new PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_JAMAICA, null);


        /*
        * Updates the bounds being used by the auto complete adapter based on the position of the
        * map.
        * */
        _map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                LatLngBounds bounds = _map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                mAdapter.setBounds(bounds);
            }
        });

        _map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        _map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        _map.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 300);
        _map.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 300);
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude()));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(new LatLng(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude()));
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue));
        _map.addMarker(options);
        _map.moveCamera(center);
        _map.animateCamera(zoom);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Permission is needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {
                location();
            }
        } else {
            location();
        }


        /*
        * Adds auto complete adapter to both auto complete
        * text views.
        * */
        try {
            starting.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            destination.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception in adpter", "" + e);
        }


        /*
        * Sets the start and destination points based on the values selected
        * from the autocomplete text views.
        * */

        starting.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        final PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                        final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);

            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
              details about the place.
              */
                        final PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    // Request did not complete successfully
                                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                                    places.release();
                                    return;
                                }
                                // Get the Place object from the buffer.
                                final Place place = places.get(0);

                                start = place.getLatLng();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
        destination.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);

            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
              details about the place.
              */
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            // Request did not complete successfully
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                            places.release();
                            return;
                        }
                        // Get the Place object from the buffer.
                        final Place place = places.get(0);

                        end = place.getLatLng();
                    }
                });

            }
        });


        /*
        These text watchers set the start and end points to null because once there's
        * a change after a value has been selected from the dropdown
        * then the value has to reselected from dropdown to get
        * the correct location.
        * */
        starting.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int startNum, int before, int count) {
                if (start != null) {
                    start = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        destination.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                if (end != null) {
                    end = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    public void sendRequest() {
        if (Util.Operations.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            route();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void route() {
        if (start == null || end == null) {
            if (start == null) {
                if (starting.getText().length() > 0) {
                    starting.setError("Choose location from dropdown.");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please choose a starting point.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if (end == null) {
                if (destination.getText().length() > 0) {
                    destination.setError("Choose location from dropdown.");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please choose a destination.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait.",
                    "Fetching route information.", true);
            Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                    .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                    .withListener(this)
                    .alternativeRoutes(true)
                    .waypoints(start, end)
                    .build();
            routing.execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (e != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingSuccess(List<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(start);
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
        _map.animateCamera(zoom);
        _map.moveCamera(center);
        if (polylines.size() > 0) {
            for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
                poly.remove();
            }
        }

        polylines = new ArrayList<>();
        //add route(s) to the map.
        for (int i = 0; i < route.size(); i++) {
            //In case of more than 5 alternative routes
            int colorIndex = i % COLORS.length;
            PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(COLORS[colorIndex]));
            polyOptions.width(10 + i * 3);
            polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
            Polyline polyline = _map.addPolyline(polyOptions);
            polylines.add(polyline);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Route " + (i + 1) + ": distance - " + route.get(i).getDistanceValue() + ": duration - " + route.get(i).getDurationValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Start marker

//        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
//        options.position(start);
//        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue));
//        _map.addMarker(options);
//
//        // End marker
//        options = new MarkerOptions();
//        options.position(end);
//        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green));
//        _map.addMarker(options);

        //change for marker points
        //String[] startlatlong =
        String startone = start.toString();
//        String[] startlatlong =startone.split(",");
//        final double sourcelatitude = Double.parseDouble(startlatlong[0]);
//        double sourcelongitude = Double.parseDouble(startlatlong[1]);
//        String[] destlatlong =  end.toString().split(",");
//        double destlatitude = Double.parseDouble(destlatlong[0]);
//        double destlongitude = Double.parseDouble(destlatlong[1]);
        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
//        System.out.println("==Sourcelatitude==="+sourcelatitude);
//        System.out.println("===destlatitude==="+destlatitude);
        id = sessionManager.getUserInfo();
        System.out.println("==Sourcelatitude===" + start.toString());
        System.out.println("===destlatitude===" + end.toString());

        communicator.getPlaces(id, start.toString(), end.toString(), new Communicator.OnResultSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object object) {
                LocationData mServerResponse = (LocationData) object;
                if (mServerResponse != null) {
                    if (mServerResponse.getStatus() != null && mServerResponse.getStatus().equals("true")) {
                        List<UserLocation> locationList = mServerResponse.getData();
                        String id = locationList.get(0).getId();
                        if (locationList == null) {
                            double sourcelatitude = Double.parseDouble(locationList.get(1).getSrclatitude());
                            double sourcelongitude = Double.parseDouble(locationList.get(2).getSrclongitude());

                            sourcelatLng = new LatLng(sourcelatitude, sourcelongitude);
                            double destlatitude = Double.parseDouble(locationList.get(3).getDestlatitude());
                            double destlongitude = Double.parseDouble(locationList.get(4).getDestlongitude());

                            destinationlatlong = new LatLng(destlatitude, destlongitude);
                            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                            options.position(sourcelatLng);
                            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue));
                            _map.addMarker(options);
                            options = new MarkerOptions();
                            options.position(destinationlatlong);
                            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green));
                            _map.addMarker(options);
                        }

                    }
                } else if (mServerResponse.getStatus() != null && mServerResponse.getStatus().equals("false")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error in getting response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailur(String fail) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingCancelled() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                location();
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void location() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return TODO;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0,
                new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);
                        _map.moveCamera(center);
                        _map.animateCamera(zoom);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                });


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

                _map.moveCamera(center);
                _map.animateCamera(zoom);


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```